# Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN not connecting to MiFi

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek

I'm using the above LM006 micro usb adapter with a Compaq PC CQ1020uk. I'm attempting to connect with a Huawei E5830 Mifi.

The Mifi shows up on the connection panel, attempts to connect but never does. It keeps asking for the password over and over, never connecting each time after 10 seconds of trying. I know the password is correct, the MiFi runs fine with my Ubuntu 11.10 notebook.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I strongly suspect there is rtl8192xx module involved. Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question to verify that.

Comment: Yes, here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852190) I filed last summer. If you ever see this, leave a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the type of authentication being used on both devices is the same (, also try to use WPA Personal instead of WPA2 on the Mifi (if possible) and the PC if the problem persists some card/drivers don't fully support it. (though a newer PC should)